# Break a replace string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell to automaticly add lines of code to certain scripts. See example below:

```
$a -replace '<div class="ef-column1 bodyContent" id="column1">', '<div class="ef-column1 body-content" id="column1"> @RenderSection("ColumnMainHeader", false)'
```

The @RenderSection part should be on a new line. So i tried to add 'n in front of @RenderSection but this will create 'n@RenderSection instead of putting @RenderSection on a new line.

I also tried 'r'n@RenderSection, but this has the same effect. putting 'n between " " will work neither.

Comment: [Are you using a single quote or a tick?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/09/07/powertip-new-lines-with-powershell/)

Comment: i am using a grave `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the single quote at the front making the grave a literal one rather than escaping the 'n.

Try using double quotes and then escaping all of the double quotes in the expression:

```
$a -replace '<div class="ef-column1 bodyContent" id="column1">', "<div class=`"ef-column1 body-content`" id=`"column1`"> `n@RenderSection(`"ColumnMainHeader`", false)"
```